# Laravel - don't render specific renderable exception

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-9, custom-error-pages

Laravel has renderable exceptions that it renders by default if they were thrown (like ModelNotFoundException, AuthenticationException, ValidationException). Is there a way to prevent this default behavior?

example: if I use the `Model::findOrFail($someId)` method and there is no model with id `$someId`, then laravel will show 404 page (because `findOrFail` method threw a ModelNotFoundException exception). But I need Laravel to process it as a normal, non-renderable exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` instead of `findOrFail`:

```php
$model = Model::find($someId);

if ($model) {
  // the model was found
} else {
  // the model was not found
}

// do other stuff here
```

Comment: Good answer, Occam's razor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the ```findOrFail``` example was just an example of a general case.